# Why vim is pasting 50 lines instead of 96?

Tags: vim

I had a file of 96 lines
i selected all lines and paste with
vim in new file but..paste only first
50 lines.
What to check?
I see this only on newest version of vim
on slackware-current,the old 14.1 paste
correctly

my vimrc

```
set nohlsearch
set mouse=""
set paste
set ruler
set clipboard=unnamedplus
setlocal cm=blowfish2
```

Comment: How did you select? How did you paste?

Comment: Could you put the code here please?

Comment: Select with y and paste with p

Comment: @elbarna, `y` doesn't *select*.  Did you use the mouse to select?  Did you use an `ex` command like `:1,96ya` or `:%ya`?  Visual mode, perhaps?  How did you select and how did you paste?  (What keystrokes?)

Comment: Whoops sorry,I meant ggVG for select(all lines_) then y for copy and p for paste

Comment: @elbarna `ggVG y p`worked for me with (at least) 1000 000 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution from the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676855/vim-limited-line-memory):

```
:help 'viminfo'
 ...
 <       Maximum number of lines saved for each register.
 ...
 :set viminfo?
 :set viminfo='100,<100,s10,h
```